# Kivy MDGridLayout fixed column size

Tags: python, kivy

```
ScrollView:
        MDGridLayout:
            id: grid_module_card
            cols: 3
            padding: 30, 30
            spacing: 30, 30
            size_hint_y: None
            height: self.minimum_height
            adaptive_height: True
            row_default_height: 500
            md_bg_color: 0.708, 0.281, 0.097, 1
```

I use .add_widget to add customized cells to the layout. When there's only 1 cell in the GridLayout, the cell takes up the whole row, but i only want it to be in the first column, taking up 1/3 of the screen. How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `col_default_width` to the width that you want for each column:

```
col_default_width: self.width/3
```

or, perhaps, more accurately:

```
col_default_width: (self.width - self.padding[0] - self.padding[2] - self.cols * self.spacing[0])/self.cols
```

There are other possibilities using the `cols_minimum` and `col_force_default` Have a look at the [GridLayout Documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.gridlayout.html).